# UIView doesn't display correctly when a method is called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I can't figure out why this UIView doesn't display correctly when the method is called. It works in another view controller. When I try it in the RootViewController the NSLog output works fine, but no view animates. I'm wondering if it does display but is hidden from view. Any help would be great.

```
 - (IBAction)showView:(id)sender{

     NSLog(@"showView button pressed");

     [self.view addSubview: menuView];
     [self.view bringSubviewToFront:menuView];

     CGRect rect = menuView.frame;
     rect.origin.x = 60;
     rect.origin.y = -400;
     menuView.frame = rect;
     [UIView beginAnimations:@"ShowView" context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; 
     rect.origin.y = 65;
     menuView.frame = rect;

     [UIView commitAnimations];

 }
```

Comment: what is logged when you call 'NSLog(@"View: %@",self.view);' below the other NSLog?

Comment: the slog out put is: View: <UIView: 0x7f6b4b0; frame = (0 0; 320 436); layer = <CALayer: 0x7f6b0c0>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked in your RootViewController, then you copied the showView: code into a new view controller and it doesn't work.  Your conversation with @kl94 explains the rest.  The menuView has been declared but not initialized in the new view controller.

I think if you go back to RootViewController where it's working, you'll find code where menuView is initialized:  ...menuView = [[SomeViewClass alloc] init.....  That code needs to get copied to the new view controller, too.  A decent place to put it is in the viewDidLoad method.

I agree with @Amiramix that the block animation is the way to go.  I'd suggest code as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // code copied from RootViewController that initializes menuView
    // probably, the frame is set so that the menu is positioned off the visible part of the view
    [self.view addSubview:menuView];
}

- (IBAction)showView:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"showView button pressed, menu view is %@", menuView);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        menuView.frame = CGRectMake(/* the rect where you want the menu to end up */);
    }];
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you well linked your menuView, which is I supposed, an IB View ?
Try to do a simple `NSLog(@"%@", menuView);` and tell us what it display.

Comment: it returns (null). I'm guessing my menuView is not linked. I'm not using IB. how would I go about linking the menuView programmatically? thanks for your help

Comment: this mean you are using a view which doesn't exist, where and how have you declared it ?

Answer (score 1):

When you add `subview` it is automatically placed in front of all other views, so no need to call `bringSubviewToFront`. Also, you need to set the frame inside the `beginAnimiation`-`commitAnimation` block. Lastly, please consider using the new `animateWithDuration` method even if only for the sake of debugging your issue, e.g.:

```
void (^block)(void) = ^{
    [self->textView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, keyboardView.origin.y)];
};

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:block];
```